# Is storing passwords to database unencrypted a _bug_?

Tags: security, testing

So I'm doing a short gig as QA engineer, building test environments, and testing. And I see passwords stored in database unencrypted. I did some reading on the topic, and it is clear that it is a bad practice.

Should I report it as a bug?

Comment: I would flag it up to your team lead...whether it's a bug depends on whether it's supposed to do that, but whether or not it's supposed to, it's a huge problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the stated requirement on the system is that passwords should be stored encrypted, then it's a bug. If there is no such explicit requirement, I would report it as a potential security weakness.

Answer (score 0):

No its not a bug but as a part of suggestion you can enforce developer to encrypt as passwords are not any simple information. but ultimately it depends on org to org. Put an authority under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

A bug is a variance from expected behavior.  If the expected behavior of your system includes "does not store passwords in plain text" or "adheres to minimal security standards", the actual behavior is a bug.  If no such expectation exists, this behavior is not a bug.  We don't know your product, so we can't answer the question of whether this behavior is a bug.  If you don't know whether a given behavior is a bug, ask the person responsible for defining your product.